# Turning column of a pandas dataframe from 4 digits to a time

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to change one column of a pandas dataframe from a format like this: `162000` to `16:20:00` (%H%M%S)

I've tried this:

```
t = mydataframe['column name']
pd.to_datetime(t, format='%H%M%S')
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'long' object is unsliceable
```

However if I don't use the format parameter I get this:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000162000
```

What's going on here?

**EDIT:**

```
t.dtype
Name: column name, dtype: int64

print t.head(5)
0    162000
1    161200
2    162400
3    163600
4    164800

t.to_dict()
{0: 162000,
 1: 161200,
 2: 162400,
 3: 163600,
 4: 164800, ...
```

**EDIT2:**

Ok, restarting the kernel of the notebook, solved that issue! Computers eh? :D

Ok, now I have this format:

```
1900-01-01 16:20:00
```

How can I change this so, that the to_datetime gives me only `16:20:00` ?

**EDIT3:**

Got it! Btw, the answer for my second question is here: [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: Working for me on Python 3.5, pandas 0.18.1

Comment: Can you show `t` and maybe `t.dtype` and `t.to_dict()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm running this on a jupyter notebook with Python 2.7.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) to get the time portion of your new `datetime` object.

```
pd.to_datetime(t, format='%H%M%S').dt.time
```

---

You also need to reassign the output of the above to your dataframe. Either assign it to a new column, or reassign it back to the original column.

To assign it to the existing column:

```
mydataframe['column name'] = pd.to_datetime(t, format='%H%M%S').dt.time
```

To assign it to a new column:

```
mydataframe['new column'] = pd.to_datetime(t, format='%H%M%S').dt.time
```

---

In either case, you get a dataframe that looks like this

```
    Times
0   16:20:00
1   16:12:00
2   16:24:00
3   16:36:00
4   16:48:00
```

Comment: I had already found a way to do it with `.dt.strftime("%H:%M")`, but this one seems simpler :) Thanks !

Comment: @RichardLuso What you had found a way to do with `strftime` is turn your column into a string column. I.e. the reverse direction of the parse you'd previously done. You couldn't calculate on that. With @Andy's approach, those are genuine, calculate-able time objects.