# Change date format of dataframe date column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this panda dataframe `df`.

```
Name      Date      Score  Score2
Joe     26-12-2007  53.45  53.4500
Joe     27-12-2007  52.38  52.7399
Joe     28-12-2007  51.71  51.8500
```

I would like to convert the date format in the `Date` column from `dd-mm-yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`. The converted dataframe will look like this;

```
Name      Date      Score  Score2
Joe     2007-12-26  53.45  53.4500
Joe     2007-12-27  52.38  52.7399
Joe     2007-12-28  51.71  51.8500
```

I am using python v3.6

EDIT: The duplicate question assumes that the original date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. However, my original date format is `dd-mm-yyyy`. If I were to apply the answer in that question, the converted dates is wrong. 
[How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```