# Change dd-mm-yyyy date format of dataframe date column to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this panda dataframe `df`.

```
Name      Date      Score  Score2
Joe     26-12-2007  53.45  53.4500
Joe     27-12-2007  52.38  52.7399
Joe     28-12-2007  51.71  51.8500
```

I would like to convert the date format in the `Date` column from `dd-mm-yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`. The converted dataframe will look like this;

```
Name      Date      Score  Score2
Joe     2007-12-26  53.45  53.4500
Joe     2007-12-27  52.38  52.7399
Joe     2007-12-28  51.71  51.8500
```

I am using python v3.6

A question marked as duplicate assumes that the original date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. However, the original date format in this question is `dd-mm-yyyy`. If I were to apply the answer in that question, the converted dates is wrong. 
[How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: Usually you only want to change the display format used to display the datetime, per [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas). **You don't want to modify the underlying data. In particular you don't want to convert to string with `.strftime('new_format')` then convert back with `pd.to_datetime`**. Why? There are multiple pitfalls in doing that (some dates might not comply with the new format, throw exceptions, mixed formats, mixed or missing timezones, etc.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `'%Y-%m-%d'`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["26-12-2007", "27-12-2007", "28-12-2007"]})
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
         Date
0  2007-12-26
1  2007-12-27
2  2007-12-28
```

Comment: This will convert the dtype to object.

Comment: This seems like only half of the answer..