# Transforming “Date” data to datetime64[ns] type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

**Context:**
I would like to transform the "Date" to `float()`, as a requirement to use the dataset for training.

**Question:**
I was wondering if Python can transform "Date" data to datetime type?

**The goal:**
Transform "Jul 24 2021" **--->** "07/24/2021"?



The dataset: **BTC Historical Data**

```
            Date        Close        High         Low        Open                 Volume (24H)   Market Cap
490 Dec 14, 2019    $7,091.76   $7,340.28   $7,040.29   $7,279.04   $17,075,801,948 69,010 BTC  $129,002,951,070
491 Dec 13, 2019    $7,279.04   $7,354.13   $7,192.74   $7,213.44   $16,667,772,107 71,176 BTC  $131,468,549,582
492 Dec 12, 2019    $7,214.58   $7,352.19   $7,127.09   $7,230.50   $18,895,200,531 102,171 BTC $131,200,636,979
493 Dec 11, 2019    $7,230.50   $7,312.27   $7,169.96   $7,242.22   $16,323,246,786 80,414 BTC  $130,567,148,332
494 Dec 10, 2019    $7,242.22   $7,409.36   $7,172.39   $7,362.61   $18,215,577,663 106,404 BTC $131,626,188,206
495 Dec 09, 2019    $7,362.61   $7,656.77   $7,309.09   $7,534.30   $17,847,629,948 122,066 BTC $133,889,762,913
496 Dec 08, 2019    $7,534.30   $7,702.15   $7,394.45   $7,510.99   $15,315,140,388 72,921 BTC  $136,960,305,336
497 Dec 07, 2019    $7,510.99   $7,699.64   $7,489.03   $7,549.93   $15,502,310,183 81,337 BTC  $136,521,384,515
498 Dec 06, 2019    $7,549.93   $7,615.61   $7,330.45   $7,400.13   $17,845,739,598 124,357 BTC $136,292,864,233
499 Dec 05, 2019    $7,400.13   $7,492.44   $7,175.62   $7,206.09   $18,880,551,089 154,696 BTC $134,769,681,329
```

Here are the codes (another context):

**My goal was to cleanse the data, to meet the criteria of `float()`**

The criteria of `float()`

- A value must not contain spaces
- A value must not contain comma
- A value must not contain non-special characters (i.e. "inf" is a special character, but "fd" is not)

So, I removed the **"$"** and **","** symbols in the dataset.

```
df = df.replace({'\$':''}, regex = True)
df = df.replace({'\,':''}, regex = True)
```

**I was trying to transform the column of "Date" and "Open" to `float()`.**

```
df = df.astype({"Open": float})
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
df.dtypes
```

**The error! :(**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    449             try:
--> 450                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    451                 dta = DatetimeArray(values, dtype=tz_to_dtype(tz))

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    416                 try:
    417                     result, timezones = array_strptime(
--> 418                         arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors
    419                     )
    420                     if "%Z" in format or "%z" in format:

pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data 'Jul 24 2021' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)
```

Comment: *"I would like to transform the "Date" to float()"* and *" The goal: Transform "Jul 24 2021" ---> "07/24/2021"?"*; which one is the goal, what's your expected output, and what does it mean to floatify datetime values?

Comment: Hello.  The goal is to transform "Jul 24 2021" to "07/24/2021" by programming it? Or would you suggest to cleanse the Excel file manually?

Comment: then you need to first *parse* and then *format*: `pd.to_datetime(df.Date, "%b %d, %Y").dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")` which is one of the duplicates listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822956/change-dd-mm-yyyy-date-format-of-dataframe-date-column-to-yyyy-mm-dd. But i'm still not sure what you meant by *"I would like to transform the "Date" to float(), as a requirement to use the dataset for training."*.

Comment: please note that the column will be of object (string) type after this operation, not datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the wrong format in `pd.to_datetime`

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b %d, %Y')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Use [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to get whatever format you want afterwards. The same placeholders from the link above apply.