# How to change date format in a column in .pkl file in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pickle, date-format

I have a file in pickle format that I import to jupyter notebook using:

```
news_data = pd.read_pickle('/Users/Final/Data/news_articles cleaned.pickle')
```

[Data has two columns as shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEPJR.png)

The Date column is in the format:
Weekday Date Month Year
eg. Monday 3rd January 2011

How can I change this format to:
Year-Month-Date
eg. 2011-01-03 ?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it "how to change date format in `.pkl` file", or "how to convert dates when reading pickled dataframe", or "how to change date format of date column in dataframe"? Or some other variation?

Comment: At any rate, you can likely find a solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822956/change-dd-mm-yyyy-date-format-of-dataframe-date-column-to-yyyy-mm-dd) thread, or any of the other dozens of threads like it.

Comment: @ddejohn I have another data set having the date format as yyyy-mm-dd. I want to merge both the data sets based on the date. But because of the difference in the date format I am unable to merge them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

with this script, you can change the date format to what you mentioned:

> How can I change this format to: Year-Month-Date eg. 2011-01-03 ?

```py
import pandas as pd
news_data = pd.read_pickle('/Users/Final/Data/news_articles cleaned.pickle')

news_data.Date = pd.to_datetime(news_data.Date)
news_data.Date = news_data.Date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

The conversion happens where i mentioned `news_data.Date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`.