# Tell python which is days and which is months

Tags: python, datetime

I have a data frame with a lot of timedata looking like this:

01-08-2018 14:02:03

I have converted it to datetime using this code:

```
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime((df["Date"]))
```

and it gives me this:
2018-01-08 14:02:03

At first glance it looks fine, but it has mistaken days for months. 
So my question is how do i tell python that days is days and month is months?

I hope some of you can help me

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], dayfirst=True)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Use `dayfirst=True`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.to_datetime("01-08-2018 14:02:03", dayfirst=True))
```

**Output:**

```
2018-08-01 14:02:03
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import pandas as pd

df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')#you will specify in the format key what each number means so it doesn't misunderstands it
```