# Change date from specific format in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I currently have a pandas `DF` with date column in the following format:

```
JUN 05, 2028
```

Expected Output:

```
2028-06-05.
```

Most of the examples I see online do not use the original format I have posted, is there not an existing solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with custom format from [`python's strftime directives`](http://strftime.org/):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['JUN 05, 2028','JUN 06, 2028']})

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%b %d, %Y')
print (df)
       dates
0 2028-06-05
1 2028-06-06
```