# Unable to convert index to date format

Tags: python, datetime

I have data which is in-64 in the Index with values like "01/11/2018" in the index. It is data that has been imported from a csv. I am unable to convert it to a "01-11-2018" format. How do I do this because I get an error message:

'time data 0 does not match format '%Y' (match)'

I got the data from the following website:
https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/spy/historical
 and you can find a ' Download this file in Excel Format ' icon at the bottom.

```
  import datetime

  spyderdat.index =  pd.to_datetime(spyderdat.index, format='%Y')
  spyderdat.head()
```

How do I format this correctly?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) must match exactly:

```
import datetime

spyderdat.index =  pd.to_datetime(spyderdat.index, format='%d/%m/%Y')
spyderdat.head()
```

Example w/o spyder:

```
import datetime

date = "1/11/2018"
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Output:

```
2018-11-01 00:00:00
```

You can `strftime` this datetime then anyhow you like. See link for formats. Or you store datetimes.

Comment: I still get the error message 'time data 0 does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)'

Comment: @AnalysisNerd this should work if you really have strings in the given format - check for None values and check the format. It has to match exactly.

Comment: the values are int64 before I format them. The data I have is "01/11/2018".

Comment: You probably already have datetime-objects - and padas is simply displaying them as you see them. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas and if its a dupe, mark yours as it

Comment: I get 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  01/11/2018 when I try spyderdat.index = pd.to_datetime(spyderdat.index )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is a string, simply converting the `/` to `-` won't fix the issue.
The real problem is that you've told [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to expect the input string to be *only a 4-digit year* but you've handed it an entire date, days and months included.

If you meant to use only the year portion you should manually extract the year first with something like `split`.
If you meant to use the full date as a value, you'll need to change your format to something like `%d/%m/%Y`.  (Although I can't tell if your input is days first or months first due to their values.)

Comment: Day First, Month Second

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Llama

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to try this

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("01/11/2018", '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: How Do i apply this to the whole index?

Comment: Thanks @mahdi n75

Comment: Your Welcom. I was trying to find your answer ;)