# Drop the year from "Year-month-date" format in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe with many columns. The first column has dates listed as "Year-Month-Date" already set as a datetime type by using:

```
df_all['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df_all['Date'].astype(str),errors='coerce')
```

The data looks like:

```
0     2008-01-01 00:00:00   100   16250.0
1     2008-01-01 00:00:00   150   13740.0
2     2008-01-01 00:00:00   200   11900.0
3     2008-01-01 00:00:00   250   10460.0
```

I wish to simply drop the year so the column reads "Month-Date" without changing the other data in the columns associated with each row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df_all['Date']` is string datatype, then you can use the str accessor with slicing like this:

```
df['Date'] = df_all['Date'].str[5:]
```

However, if `df_all['Date']` is a datetime dtype then you can the date accessor with `strfttime`:

```
df_all['Date'] = df_all['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
             Date    A        B
0  01-01 00:00:00  100  16250.0
1  01-01 00:00:00  150  13740.0
2  01-01 00:00:00  200  11900.0
3  01-01 00:00:00  250  10460.0
```