# How can I remove the last 6 digits from all rows in a set column of integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns, one of which is dates formatted like 2021-05-01 and I would like to remove the day and month and only have the year. I tried:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y')
```

But apparently at least one of the rows has "00" for the month and/or day so this returned an error. I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55957506/drop-the-year-from-year-month-date-format-in-a-pandas-dataframe) but it returned the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I'm very much a beginner and not sure what to do here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible extract year by format `YYYY` use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['year'] = df['date'].str.extract('(\d{4})', expand=False)
```

Or filter first 4 digits:

```
df['year'] = df['date'].str[:4]
```

Or remove last 6 digits:

```
df['year'] = df['date'].str[-6:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dt.year`

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.year
```

Comment: `But apparently at least one of the rows has "00" for the month and/or day so this returned an error.` - So `pd.to_datetime(df.date)` failed.

Comment: @jezrael That is true. I would advise the row to be dropped as the day/month should not be 00. The year information should also be dirty data.

Comment: @RaymondToh if it was real data I would've dropped it, but it's for homework so I'm supposed to have all the rows :)