# Pandas: Timestamp conversion to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, pandas

I keep getting these results:

```
0   2019-02-28 19:24:18.101586+00:00
1   2019-03-01 08:33:15.668978+00:00
[...]
Name: created, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

However, my goal is to get these results:

```
0   2019-02-28
1   2019-03-01
```

Do you see what I am doing wrong?

```
# Load data
def load_ticket_data():
    df = pd.read_csv(
        'wolfsburg/tickets_ticket.csv',
        usecols=['created', 'start_at'],
        parse_dates=['created', 'start_at'],
    )
    return df

tickets = load_ticket_data()
test = pd.to_datetime(tickets['created'], format='%y/%m/%d')
print(test)
```

Comment: try: `tickets['created'] = tickets['created'].dt.strftime('%y/%m/%d')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: @PV8 - no, it is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need datetimes with no times use [`Series.dt.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) with [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
tickets['created'] = tickets['created'].dt.tz_localize(None).dt.floor('d')
print (tickets)
     created
0 2019-02-28
1 2019-03-01

print (tickets.dtypes)
created    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: The second one gives me the expected result. However `dtype` is changing to an object. Before it was `datetime64`. Is `pd.to_datetime` in general the wrong approach? I thought that's the idea of that method.

Comment: @JoeyCoder - exactly it means `python object`, I think `dt.floor` is necessary here, it not working for you?

Comment: `dt.floor` is working but it makes the "impression" that the event happened at 00:00:00 which would be "wrong" information I give to my model. I will try to work with the `python object`. I just wonder why `pd.to_datetime`doesn't work that way.

Comment: @JoeyCoder - Tested and you are right, need `'remove'` UTC, answer was edited.