# How to I change date format in python such that when I export to excel the date matches my computer date settings

Tags: python, date, format

Is there a way to format data frame dates column such that when I export the data to excel the dates matches the date settings of the computer of any pc that is used to open the file.

Comment: Are you using pandas? You could try [dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), though this returns strings, not datetime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)