# How to remove date and leave time in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am downloading data from FXCM with fxcmpy, this is what the data looks like:

[image: data downloaded]

In the index column I would like only to have the time without the date how can this be done.

This is the code:

```
import fxcmpy
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

con = fxcmpy.fxcmpy(config_file='fxcm.cfg', server='demo')

# To check if the connection is established
if(con.is_connected):
    print('Connection is established')
else:
    print('Erro in connecting to the server')

data = con.get_candles('USD/JPY', period='m5', number=500)

con.close()
```

Comment: Could you please check my solution once and lemme know if that helped you? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your index is already a `DatetimeIndex`, simply choose the time part from the index:

```
data.index = data.index.time
```

If it is not (say, it is a string), convert it to `DatetimeIndex` **first**:

```
data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your df['Index'].dtype has type pandas datetime type `dtype('<M8[ns]')`. Then you use the following format to extract time. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

```
 df['Index'].dt.strftime('%H:%m:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is converting object to datetime then extract year from it.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
date="2019-11-21 13:10:00"
fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
print(dt.strptime(date,fmt).time())
```

output

```
13:10:00
```