# Convert a date to a different format for an entire new column

Tags: python, loops, date, datetime

I want to convert the date in a column in a dataframe to a different format. Currently, it has this format: **'2019-11-20T01:04:18'**. I want it to have this format: **20-11-19 1:04**.

I think I need to develop a loop and generate a new column for the new date format. So essentially, in the loop, I would refer to the initial column and then generate the variable for the new column in the format I want.

Can someone help me out to complete this task?

The following code works for one occasion:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-11-20T01:04:18', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
print d.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [previous answer in this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38067805/1831811) , this should be able to help you, comments give explanation
You can read your data into pandas from csv or database or create some test data as shown below for testing.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'column': {0: '26/1/2016', 1: '26/1/2016'}})
>>> # First convert the column to datetime datatype
>>> df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df.column)
>>> # Then call the datetime object format() method, set the modifiers you want here
>>> df['column'] = df['column'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') 

>>> df
                 column
0  2016-01-26T00:00:00
1  2016-01-26T00:00:00
```

NB. Check to ensure that all your columns have similar date strings

Comment: Thank a lot, also how do I create a new column that says the week number? For example week 45, 46 etc.

Comment: You can do something like first change column to datetime `df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df.column)` then call `>>> df['week'] = df['column'].dt.week` , this uses the dt.week value from the dt object

Comment: documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.week.html

Answer (score 0):

You can either achieve it like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

df['your_column'] = df['your_column'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M'))
```

Comment: This is the error I get when I do that: "ValueError: unconverted data remains: +01:00"

Comment: your column contains some dates which doesn't have the format you mentioned, you have some date like this `'2019-11-20T01:04:18+01:00'`

Comment: I just noticed, so what do you advise on that?

Comment: you can either user `parse`function of `dateutil.parser`if you care about timezone offset, otherwise use slice `x[:19]` to convert the part that follow your format