# Filtering and Format dataframe from Webscrape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am new to Python, but know R decently. I am trying to webscrape stock price data from yahoo. I successfully retrieved the price data and able to create a dataframe. However, yahoo includes when dividends are paid out. For now, I would like to ignore dividends, but I am having trouble filtering the dataframe to remove when dividends are paid out. Also, I would like to change the format of the `Date` column, for example, from `Mar 14, 2000` to `%Y-%m-%d`.

From webscrape:

```
Date           Open            Close
Dec 23, 2019   0.611 Dividend  None
Dec 01, 2019   88.38           88.90
```

First, I tried do filter on the `'None'`, but that is an empty dataframe: `df.loc[df.Close=='None']`

Second I tried to replace the `Dividend` aspect of the `Open` column with a function similar to gsub in R, but may have done it incorrectly. The idea being I can remove the value in that cell and replace with a new value, `toRemove`, then filter on this new value:

```
re.sub('Dividend','Remove',df.Open,flags=re.I)
```

Within R, I know you can use `str(df)` to get the structure of a dataframe and Python uses `df.dtypes`, but this returned `object` for me, which I didn't know what to do with in order to fix the date issue.

Code used for Webscrape:

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VT/history?period1=1547078400&period2=1607558400&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo'

source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()      
soup =bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
tr = soup.find_all('tr')

data = []

# formats price data
for table in tr:
    td = table.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    data.append(row)        

# labels columns
columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'AdjClose', 'Volume']

data = data[1:-2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = columns
```

Comment: Is not better get just <strong> element?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to solve for the dividend issue. Instead of appending the row, then filtering, don't include the row all together. Essentially,

```
for table in tr:
        td = table.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        if len(row)>1: # for each row, but the last "*Close price adjusted for splits...."
            if ('Dividend' not in row[1]): # removes the dividend column
                data.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas/38067805) should answer your date question. As for filtering, you should probably learn to use the `df.loc[]` functionality. [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/pandas) has an excellent resource for learning dataframe manipulation in Pandas. Granted, I do not use `loc` in this solution.

Anyways, using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [lambda functions](https://stackabuse.com/lambda-functions-in-python/), we can quickly iterate over every row and make the changes to your `Open` column as follows.

```
df['Open'] = df.apply(lambda row: float(row['Open'].split()[0]), axis=1)
```

I tested this on your dataframe and it works. In this case, `df.apply()` with  `axis=1` will apply some sort of function to every row. Here, we have chosen to use a lambda function. It's worth noting you can name 'row' whatever you want here, but basically it takes in a row named row, and then you can apply any operations you wish to it.

I chose to pull the `Open` column value for each row with `row['Open']`, then split that string on spaces using `.split()`, and from there you can take the first string (which we know to be the number) using indexing with `[0]`. finallly, I wrapped that in a `float()` cast to make sure it was a float and not a string.

Learning to use `apply()` and lambda functions together is extremely valuable in pandas. Also that kaggle site would be worth checking out at least for the pandas tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for the Kaggle suggestion, I have actually done those classes, but still have a lot to retain and review. But your answer for Open, removes the Dividends, while I need to find a way to filter and remove Dividends. My idea involves changing the cell value, then filtering on the new cell value.

Comment: ah I see. Yes they are a lot of information for sure. Could you elaborate on what you're  trying to achieve with the dividends column?

Comment: Dividends is not a column, but a row. Essentially, remove all the rows that contain dividend info.