# How to remove the colon from formatted time value in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a column named "Start Time". It is a string and it displays the time as 11:20:15. I want to have the time in the format 112015. So I need to replace the colon.

I have tried:

```
["Start Time"] = df["Start Time"].replace(":","", regex=True)
```

But that didn't work. It didn't give an error either but the time remains 11:20:15.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `df["Start Time"].str.replace(":","")`?

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives an error message:can only use dt accessor with stringvalues which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: Use `df["Start Time"].dt.strftime(%H%M%S)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did:

```
df['Start Time'] = df['Start Time'].astype(str)
```

And then:

```
["Start Time"] = df["Start Time"].replace(":","", regex=True)
```

It worked perfectly. Thank you all for thinking with me!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `.str` to handle each value as a str and apply `.replace()` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html)) :

```
df["Start Time"] = df["Start Time"].str.replace(":","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `df["Start Time"]` column a string datatype? Often pandas will read in dates as datetime objects. You can check this by printing `df.dtypes` and see if it says `object` for this column.

Then I'd recommend using `df.strftime` (string formatter) as done here: [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas/38067805) if you really want the string in the format you mentioned.

Comment: It is indeed a object. I will check the explanation in the link. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help! Definitely do, getting familiar with handling dates is something that will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: Still trying here. I tried df['Start Time'] = df['Start Time'].dt.strftime(format='%H%M%S'), but then I get the error message "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". Does this mean that I have to change the dtype of this column to datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a datatime object in  `Start Time` column. Use `dt.strftime(%H%M%S)`

**Ex:**

```
df["Start Time"].dt.strftime(%H%M%S)
```