# Command to print top 10 rows of python pandas dataframe without index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`head()` prints the indexes.
`dataframe.to_string(index=False,max_rows=10)` prints the first 5 and last 5 rows.

Comment: print(ndf.head().style.hide_index()) just prints the following: <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x0000020E908D5EC8>

Comment: **Omit `print()`**, use **only** `ndf.head().style.hide_index()`. — You have to work in Jupyter Notebook (or JupyterLab) environment. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357424/7023590).

Answer (score 7):

You should try this :

```
print(df.head(n=10).to_string(index=False))
```

This will work because `df.head` return a `Dataframe` object so you can apply the `to_string` method to it and get rid of that index ^^.

Answer (score 2):

If you like complicated solutions, you may use

```
[print(row) for row in df.head().to_string(index=False).split("\n")]
```

---

The explanation:

- `df.head().to_string(index=False)` returns a string with `"\n"` as row delimiters,
- `split()` method then returns a list of single rows,
- `[print(row) for row in ...]` then prints every row.

---

*It was a joke,* of course, albeit giving you the desired result. Printing it as a whole string will give *the same result* (as every row ends with `"\n"`):

```
print(df.head().to_string(index=False))
```

---

If you work with [Jupyter Notebook](https://ipython.org/notebook.html), you may use a nicer command

```
df.head().style.hide_index()
```

**Be careful!**

No `print(...)`, no `df = ...`. The returning object is an object of the `Styler` class, **not** a dataframe.

Jupyter Notebook IDE *automatically* calls its method `._repr_html()` to render (display) your table.

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60273382/7023590) for details.