# try to convert a data frame column of format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' to '"%d %b %Y" and ignoring other format/dtype present in same column

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I tried below mention code but unable to execute successfully, it happening due to other type entry in the same column

```py
df['column1']=df['column1'].dt.strftime("%d %b %Y")
```

getting 
`AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

sample of dataframe:(picture attached)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: no... actually i have to ignore the other format entry available in the column

Comment: added of data frame sample, hope it will give you more clear idea

Comment: Better than a table would be minimal code sample which creates this table and fills with two values - one having right format and second not. It will be easier for us to execute it, see error and propose fix.

Comment: @ŁukaszŚlusarczyk can you please add some example

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def converter(x):
    try:
        return(datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%b %d %Y"))
    except:
        return x
```

```py
df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(converter)
```

Comment: thanks, but I  try to write the code in which we just convert the right format else ignore the other cases, in the same column instead of creating other columns