# Python /Pandas / pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert date column (datetime64[ns]) into day-month-year format with this code ,

```
pd.to_datetime(final['Date'],format = ('%d-%b-%Y'))
```

but it remains the same:

```
0     2019-12-31
1     2020-01-01
2     2020-01-02
3     2020-01-03
4     2020-01-04
         ...    
112   2020-04-21
113   2020-04-22
114   2020-04-23
115   2020-04-24
116   2020-04-25
```

Comment: you use `to_datetime` to parse string to datetime. the other way round (datetime to string), you use `strftime`. Besides that, yyyy-mm-dd is just how `pandas` displays a date in a df, with a column of dtype datetime64[ns]. if you want the column to be dtype datetime64[ns], I guess you have to live with that.

Comment: @MrFuppes do you know any way to change format into dd-mm-yyyy but keep type as datetime ? It is not necessary datetime64[ns]

Comment: I think not, see also e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas) question... Why do you want to change it? It's just a matter of display...

Comment: @MrFuppes because in Armenia we use dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: well, in Germany, we normally use dd.mm.yyyy - however for working with date and time, I would always prefer [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)! If you want to display data for a presentation etc., you're right, it is better to use *local* conventions. For that, you have `strftime()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

are you spelling month wrong? it says -%b instead of -%m

Comment: it worked , but dtype changed into object . How can I keep it as datetime64[ns] or something like that