# ValueError: time data 'May 11, 2015' does not match format '%m%y%d' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am using pandas, and I have a column that contains datetime.

[image: My DataFrame that contains Date values]

How can I represent this datetime string in a proper way?

I did

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m%y%d')
```

But it gave me the error:

`ValueError: time data 'May 11, 2015' does not match format '%m%y%d' (match)`

Does anybody know how to solve that? Or is there a way that I can do this date transformation in a better way?

Comment: "BONUS" is quite an unfortunate term & way to pack a 2nd different question here, without offering any info for it (where exactly does it happen?). Please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post - you can always open a separate question for your second issue (and link here, if necessary). Plus, question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: WHY would you think that `'%m%y%d'` is a match for `'May 11, 2015'` ??

Comment: My purpose is to format the `May 11, 2015` in a way that is `2015-05-11`.

Comment: kindly spend some time on https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes   to read up the format strings for datetime formatting. You can change the default setting how pandas displays date - gimme a sek Ill search you the next duplicate:  [how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: `'%b %d,%Y'` --> `%b` for Month name like Jan, Feb, Mar...`%d` for day, `%Y` for year with centry like 1990, 2020 etc.

Comment: @PatrickArtner When I use `pd.to_datetime`, I get something like this:
.
 `['2019-10-14T00:00:00.000000000'],`.

Comment: This is a datetime object - exactly what you do when you convert the string into a datetime - if you want to get a STRING of format '%m%y%d you need to do both. first parse your string into a datetime object, then create a a string from the datetimeobject.  `df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b %d, %Y').dt.strftime('%m%y%d')` - `df = pd.DataFrame( {"date":["May 20, 2020"]})` + `df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d, %Y')` + `df['date3'] = df['date2'].dt.strftime('%d%m%Y')`