# How to extract a date from a SQL Server Table and store it in a variable in Pandas without noise, only the date

Tags: python, pandas

I try to extract a date from a SQL Server Table. I get my query to return it like this:

`Hours = pd.read_sql_query("select * from tblAllHours",con)`

Now I convert my "Start" Column in the Hours dataframe like this:

`Hours['Start'] =  pd.to_datetime(Hours['Start'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`

then I select the row I want in the column like this:

`StartDate1 =  Hours.loc[Hours.Month == Sym1, 'Start'].values`

Now, if I print my variable `print(StartDate1)` I get this result:

`[datetime.date(2020, 10, 1)]`

What I need is actually `2020-10-01`

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You currently have a column of datetimes. The format you're requesting is a string format
- Use [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html#pandas-series-dt-strftime) to convert the datetime to a string
- `pd.to_datetime(Hours['Start'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`: `format` tells the parser what format your dates are in, so they can be converted to a datetime, it is not a way to indicate the format you want the datetime.

  - Review [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)
- If you want only the values, not the [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), use [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) at the end of the following command, as you did in the question.

```py
start_date_str = Hours.Start.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

try

`print(Hours['Start'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').values)`

result is a list of YYYY-MM-dd

`['2020-07-03', '2020-07-02']`

a bit similar to this [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)