# Python : How to reorder date column in dataframe with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have a df with values :

```
name      age 
 
mark    2002-12-19    
tom     2003-11-30
```

how to reorder the date format with dd mm yyyy

```
name      age 
 
mark    19-12-2002    
tom     30-11-2003
```

tried this [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

but it is storing as string. i need in date format

Comment: November doesn't have 31 days

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date stamps are valid, which your second one appears to not be.

```
df['age'] = pd.to_datetime(df['age']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '30-07-2018'`

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc[:, "age"] = pd.to_datetime(df["age"], format="%Y-%m-%d").dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")`

you can then use `.sort_values()` to sort the dates as you wish.