# Convert pandas dataframe datetime format in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

have a df with values name and age with datetime format

```
name      age 
 
mark    2002-12-19 18:39
```

how to reorder the date format with this format

```
name      age 
 
mark    2002-12-19T18:39:00.000+00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly set your display format [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas/38067805)

Code below has problems....   the data type of age has been changed to string from datetime64

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"name":"mark", "age":pd.to_datetime("2002-12-19 18:39")}])
df["age"] = df["age"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print(df.to_string(index=False))
df.dtypes
```

**output**

```
 name                          age
 mark  2002-12-19T18:39:00.000000Z
name    object
age     object
dtype: object
```