# Fill date gap with NaN and interpolate 5 min resolution data

Tags: python, date, interpolation, nan

i'm using python and
i need to fill the date gaps with NaN values, my data looks like this:

```
"Date & Time","High Temp - °C","Low Temp - °C"
"12/4/19 00:00","0.0","-0.1"
"12/4/19 00:05","-0.1","-0.1"
"12/4/19 00:10","0.1","-0.1"
"12/4/19 00:25","0.1","0.1"
"12/4/19 00:30","0.2","0.1"
```

and i would like to have them like this:

```
"Date & Time","High Temp - °C","Low Temp - °C"
"12/4/19 00:00","0.0","-0.1"
"12/4/19 00:05","-0.1","-0.1"
"12/4/19 00:10","0.1","-0.1"
"12/4/19 00:15","NaN","NaN"
"12/4/19 00:20","NaN","NaN"
"12/4/19 00:25","0.1","0.1"
"12/4/19 00:30","0.2","0.1"
```

after that i would like to interpolate the data to substitute the missing values.

what i have tried is:

```
#%%
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv(Path().joinpath('C:....d_data\\..._data.csv'))


data['Date & Time']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date & Time'],format='%m/%d/%Y %hh:%mm')
data = data.sort_values(by=['Date & Time'], ascending=[True])
data.set_index('Date & Time', inplace=True)
print (data)
```

Comment: What language are you writing this in? What have you tried? How many rows do you need? What do you mean by adding NaN and "after that" interpolating the values?

Comment: i'm writing it in python. I need more than 20000 rows. i need to interpolate the missing values with 5 min resolution

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to explain that, and to include the Python code you've written so far, and details of what the current result is. Note that this is not a code-writing service, so you need to make an attempt and ask for specific help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `resample` the data as the following :

```
import pandas as pd

# reading the csv 
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',parse_dates=['Date & Time'],index_col=0)

# resampling the data for every 5 min
df = df.resample('5T').mean()
print(df)
```

Output :

```
 Date & Time               High Temp - °C  Low Temp - °C                        
 2019-12-04 00:00:00             0.0           -0.1
 2019-12-04 00:05:00            -0.1           -0.1
 2019-12-04 00:10:00             0.1           -0.1
 2019-12-04 00:15:00             NaN            NaN
 2019-12-04 00:20:00             NaN            NaN
 2019-12-04 00:25:00             0.1            0.1
 2019-12-04 00:30:00             0.2            0.1
```

Comment: Thanks, when i run the code i get this error: "pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate"  it seems that is not recognizing some inputs. When i open the file in Excel i have different date formats, example: 16.00 and 04.00PM

Comment: For me, it works fine. May be you could add `df = df.astype('float')` above `df = df.resample('5T').mean()`. You could use the following the change the datetime format in `pandas` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: Thanks Vikas, still not working. The problem is that i can convert some dates into numbers but not all of them. So i have this error: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: --"

Comment: Can you share/link of  a screenshot of `print(df.info())`.

Comment: The problem is related to the data format. How can i change the data format? in the original data is dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm. But when i resample it reads it like mm/dd/yyyy hh/mm thus creating a wrong output.

Comment: Maybe not. I think it is pandas way to read datetime. if the datatype is `datetime64[ns]`, then it shouldn't be a problem. My concern is that some of your data in not being read numeric(int or float) and becoming string. That's why I asked  `print(df.info())`, which will tell us the datatype of each column.