# time data doesn't match format specified when it seemed to be match

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have dataframe in pandas that has two dates columns:

```
>>>ID  name    start        end  
0  12  Tik     1/6/2020    None
1  32  Tak     12/31/2019  None
2  45  Tek     9/1/2019   1/30/2020
3  78  Tok     9/1/2019   1/29/2020
```

I'm trying to convert those dates into datetime to be in format of Y-m-d e.g that 12/31/2019 will be 2019-12-31 :

```
df[['start','end']] =df[['start','end']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format=''%Y-%m-%d'')
```

but whenever I run this I get error:

> ValueError: time data 1/6/2020 doesn't match format specified

I have tried than to specify the format to be like the given date (e.g (d-m-Y):

```
df[['start','end']] =df[['start','end']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format=''%d-%m-%Y'')

>>>ValueError: time data '1/6/2020' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y' (match)
```

I have tried to break it as suggest in the first answer here: [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)
and to first conver to  datetime and then use strftime but in the first line I got the error that Ineed to specify the format.

I can't find any reason why is this happen, maybe is because the day and month do not have two digits?

my end goal is to convert those date columns into %Y-%m-%d format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The issue seems to be the use of two sets of quotes around the format

  - `''...''`
- The `format` parameter of [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) specifies the current format of the column, not the desired format.

  - The format of these dates is `'%m/%d/%Y'`

```py
import pandas as pd

# setup the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [12, 32, 45, 78], 'name': ['Tik', 'Tak', 'Tek', 'Tok'], 'start': ['1/6/2020', '12/31/2019', '9/1/2019', '9/1/2019'], 'end': [None, None, '1/30/2020', '1/29/2020']})

# convert to datetime
df[['start','end']] = df[['start','end']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%m/%d/%Y')

# display(df)
   ID name      start        end
0  12  Tik 2020-01-06        NaT
1  32  Tak 2019-12-31        NaT
2  45  Tek 2019-09-01 2020-01-30
3  78  Tok 2019-09-01 2020-01-29
```