# Date conversion in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My data frame looks like -

```
date        cnt
2020-05-09  301
2020-07-09  402
2020-08-09  403
2020-09-09  402
2020-09-14  512
2020-10-09  403
2020-11-09  403
```

I want my data frame looks like -

```
date        cnt
2020-09-05  301
2020-09-07  402
2020-09-08  403
2020-09-09  402
2020-09-14  512
2020-09-10  403
2020-09-11  403
```

On 14th september i.e 2020-09-14 is correct but rest of the date I need to convert in '%Y-%m-%d'.How to do in python?My code is given below -

```
df['date'] = pd.df(df['date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: Please post a sample of the raw data, as it comes from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
df = DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'Alfa': [1, 2, 3],
     'Bravo': [4, 5, 6],
     'Date': [datetime.strftime(datetime.now()-timedelta(days=_), "%m/%d/%Y") for _ in range(3)]},
    orient='index',
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C']).T
print(df)
#   Alfa Bravo        Date
#  A    1     4  10/03/2020
#  B    2     5  10/02/2020
#  C    3     6  10/01/2020

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df)
#   Alfa Bravo        Date
#  A    1     4  2020-10-03
#  B    2     5  2020-10-02
#  C    3     6  2020-10-01
```

Comment: It's not working...no change in my data frame

Comment: @JohnDavis you didnt supply your data, so I can't seem to understand the result that you get. Maybe you can add it. The solution I provided solve the issue in my specific example.

Comment: @JohnDavis Did you try my solution? What kind of errors did you encounter if any?

Comment: @JohnDavis thanks for the accept. I would also appreciate an upvote if possible

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough details in your question, but if your `date` column is already a date value rather than a string value, I'm guessing your problem was during the initial load of the dates.

If you loaded your data via pandas `pd.read_csv()` then there are a lot of options for loading dates, including options that will try to detect the date format automatically.  Several (but not all rows) in your sample data would confuse this automatic detection (it can't tell which part is the month or day).

If the `date` column is already a date value, then

`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')`

will not do anything useful.

If you did use `pd.read_csv()` and the dates are YYYY-MM-DD on disk try using this instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
myDateLoader = lambda d: np.datetime64('NaT') if d == '' or d == 'NULL' or d.startswith('9999-12-31') else np.datetime64(datetime.strptime(d[:10], '%Y-%m-%d'))
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters={'date': myDateLoader})
```

If they are not YYYY-MM-DD on disk, then adjust the above format as needed.