# How do I convert YYYYMMDD to datetime, but maintain the same format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have an variable integer that is in the format YYYYMMDD.

How do i convert that variable to datetime while maintaining the format of YYYYMMDD?

```
date = 20200930

nextday = date + 1
```

How do i fix this, so the `nextday` variable displays as `20201001`

Comment: So what's wrong? It's easier to get advice and answers by showing in the program source what you want to do in that format and what you couldn't do (the problem you encountered).

Comment: Can you please give more details about your use case? You can work with datetime objects and print them/save them in the format you're giving.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60273382/7023590

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you need to do correctly, you can easily do it using the datetime package.

First, convert your variable to a date:

```
import datetime
date = 20200930
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y%m%d')
```

Now, when you print this, you will see:
`datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 30, 0, 0)`.

You can then add a day to it:

```
dt_new = dt + datetime.timedelta(1)
```

And specify the format you want to see the new date variable in:

```
print ('{date: %Y%m%d}'.format(date=dt_new))
```

which will give:
`20201001`.