# Changing Date Type of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, date

I have a large pandas dataframe. One of my columns is a time column, and it currently looks like this `2014-01-01T00:52:00Z`.

I want it to look like
`1/1/14 00:55`, but I have no idea how to make the dates look like this for an entire column of a dataframe?

---

Another example: `2014-10-24T08:55:00Z` becomes `10/24/14 08:55`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: @MykolaZotko not really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a for loop similar to the following. It should work well for you!

```
for item in file['Date_Time']:
        if item[5] != "0": #Oct, Nov, Dec
            newdat = item[5:7] + "/" + item[8:10] + "/" + item[2:4] + " " + item[11:16]
        else:
            newdat = item[6] + "/" + item[8:10] + "/" + item[2:4] + " " + item[11:16]
        file['New_Date_Time'] = newdat
```

Run this on the column you want to change. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following function to convert time format as you wish:

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert(date_string):
    format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
    date_struct = datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
    new_date_string = datetime.strftime(date_struct, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    return new_date_string

date_string = "2014-10-24T08:55:00Z"
print (convert(date_string))
```

And here is the result:

```
10/24/2014 08:55
```