# Format in sorting an array of dates in Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, date, datetime

I have this dataframe, sales and the column, dates.
[image]

[image]

When I try to see the range of dates, it shows me them like this. It shows the last date, 31.10.2015, somewhere in the middle instead of the end of this array.

```
In: sales.date.unique()
Out: array(['01.01.2013', '01.01.2014', '01.01.2015', ..., '31.10.2015',
       '31.12.2013', '31.12.2014'], dtype=object)
```

when I have tried to sort these dates with

sales.date.sort_values(), it still gives me  '31.12.2014' as the last date.

then, I converted my dates to datetime64[ns] with

```
sales["date"] = pd.to_datetime(sales["date"],format = "%d.%m.%Y")
sales["date"] = pd.to_datetime(sales["date"],format = "%d.%m.%Y")
dates = sales.date.sort_values()

dates.unique()
```

I got this format

```
array(['2013-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2013-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2013-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', ...,
       '2015-10-29T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-10-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2015-10-31T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

How can I remove the 'T00:00:00.000000000' part? I have specified format = "%d.%m.%Y" in pd_todatetime..

sorry if that's somewhat a basic question. thank you for your help.

Comment: `df['DOB1'] = df['DOB'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas

Comment: The format you specified in `to_datetime` is for **reading** the string data to convert them to the internal datetime format (datetime64[ns]) used by pandas. What you see in the output of `dates.unique()` is just the standard string representation of the datetime64 values of this array.

Comment: this has helped me, thanks guys! not sure how to vote for 'solved my problem'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sales['date'] = sales['date'].dt.strftime('%Y/%d/%m')
dates = sales.date.sort_values()
dates.unique()

Out:
array(['2013/01/01', '2013/01/02', '2013/01/03', ..., '2015/31/07','2015/31/08', '2015/31/10'], dtype=object)
```

thank you for the comments above!