# Python, how to replace a column of dataframe with isoformat date with simple date?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe "df" in Python where one column is the date represented in isoformat "2017-01-01T12:30:59.000000".

```
df['date']
Out[1]: 
0        2020-02-24T18:00:00
1        2020-02-24T18:00:00
2        2020-02-24T18:00:00
```

Is there a single command to replace the entire column in simple date like ?

```
df['date']
Out[1]: 
0        2020-02-24
1        2020-02-24
2        2020-02-24
```

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

Cast your string date to actual datetime and then get only the date from `.dt`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2020-02-24T18:00:00","2020-02-24T18:00:00","2020-02-24T18:00:00"]})

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.date
```