# How to convert time into specific format in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, rows

I have a column of time in my pandas DataFrame containing more than 800,000 rows. The time format is something like this:

```
08:28:31
08:28:35
08:28:44
08:28:44
```

I want to convert this format into hourly, which means if the first time comes 08:28:31 then the second-time time should come in hour by hour 09:28:31 etc. How do we achieve this in python using the DateTime library

output data:

```
08:28:31
09:28:31
...
23:28:31

08:28:35
09:28:35
...
23:28:35

08:28:44
...
08:28:44
...
```

Comment: Please Rephrase , that what you are asking . I cant understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: @jezrael yes exactly!

Comment: 3rd ->10:28:31 , 4th-> 11:28:31, 5th->12:28:31 and so on !

Comment: yes ! exactly .

Comment: OK, added to question what I mean expected ouput from input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert values to datetimes
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#count number of repeated values
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(24 - df['date'].dt.hour)]
#generate hour timedeltas
hours = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='H')

#add to dates and generate times with convert index to default values
s = df['date'].add(hours).dt.time.reset_index(drop=True)
print (s)
0     08:28:31
1     09:28:31
2     10:28:31
3     11:28:31
4     12:28:31
  
59    19:28:44
60    20:28:44
61    21:28:44
62    22:28:44
63    23:28:44
Length: 64, dtype: object
```

Comment: What if we want to take the time after every 15 minutes . Is it possible ?

Comment: @OfficialDeveloper - Can you try change `hours = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='H')` to `hours = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='Min') * 15` ?

Comment: As you told me that Use df.groupby('Time', as_index=False)['Price'].mean() , if duplicates occurs , I have to take the mean of only duplicated rows not entire column

Comment: @OfficialDeveloper - yop, but if use `mean` of not duplicates get same values, so solution working well.