# Pandas, format date from dd/mm/yyyy to MMM dd/yy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, strftime

I would like to change the date from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `MMM dd/yy`.
ie `15/04/2021` to `APR 15/21`

My `Date` column format is `object`

I am doing this:
`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%MMM %DD/%YY')`

but I am getting `ValueError: time data '15/04/2021' does not match format '%MMM %dd/%yy' (match)`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For which usage? display dataframe in a console, export to excel?

Comment: Yes. display in dataframe for eventual excel use.

Comment: If you convert a string datetime to a `datetime64` dtype, the display will be always in the format "YYYY-MM-DD". See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38067805/15239951).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['15/04/2021', '12/05/2021', '4/6/2021']})
>>> df
         Date
0  15/04/2021
1  12/05/2021
2    4/6/2021

>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
>>> df
        Date
0 2021-04-15
1 2021-12-05
2 2021-04-06

>>> df['date_formated'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b %d/%y').str.upper()
>>> df
        Date date_formated
0 2021-04-15     APR 15/21
1 2021-12-05     DEC 05/21
2 2021-04-06     APR 06/21

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------         --------------  -----         
 0   Date           3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   date_formated  3 non-null      object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(1)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
```

Comment: get an error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: I have fixed the data format in the updated code

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear, I wanted to make it like `15/04/2021` to `APR 15/21`

Comment: Hi @excelguy Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert your original `Date` column to `datetime` format (pandas will read dates as a strings by default). After doing so, just change the display format.

Try this:

```py
# Convert to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')

# Solution for title: change display to 'MMM dd/y'
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b %d/%y').astype(str).str.upper()

# Solution for comment: change display to 'MMM dd y'
df['Date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%b %d %y').astype(str).str.upper()
```

Comment: Thanks arturo but I would  like format `APR 15 21`

Comment: I edited my code to match it exactly. That is, month in CAPS and removed the '/'. Did that do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
df.loc['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%b %d/%y').str.upper()
```

Comment: Make sure the Data column contains no NAN values. If it does then handle them before using this :)

Comment: thanks! seems to work! however getting this msg: `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: You need to add .loc df.loc['Date']

Comment: so `.loc df.loc['Date'] = ...` ?

Comment: thanks works! but seems to have made 1 extra row to my dataframe with the word Date and the row with Nan's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231656/discussion-between-nk03-and-excelguy).