# How can convert string to date which only contains year number?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, format

Create a dataframe whose first column is a text.

```
import pandas as pd
values = {'dates':  ['2019','2020','2021'],
          'price': [11,12,13]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['dates','price'])
```

Check the dtypes:

```
df.dtypes
dates    object
price     int64
dtype: object
```

Convert type in the column `dates` to type `dates`.

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%Y')
df
       dates  price
0 2019-01-01     11
1 2020-01-01     12
2 2021-01-01     13
```

I want to convert the type in `dates` column to `date` and the dates in the following format----contains only year number:

```
    dates  price
0 2019     11
1 2020     12
2 2021     13
```

How can achieve the target?

Comment: There is not a a date type which is only the year. Minimally dates need a year, month and day. If an element is missing it will be provided. Typically the default missing day and month is the first. What are you trying to do where an `int` value does not work? Or what are you trying to do that the date being the first of the year does not work?

Comment: @AnuragDabas I was providing a (I hope meaningful) answer, can you reopen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to have the `datetime` format for your columns, it is likely to benefit from it. What you see in the column ("2019-01-01") is a representation of the `datetime` object. The realquestion here is, why do you need to have a `datetime` object?

##### Actually, I don't care about `datetime` type:

Use a string ('2019'), or preferentially an integer (2019) which will enable you to perform sorting, calculations, etc.

##### I need the `datetime` type but I really want to see only the year:

Use [`style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) to format your column while retaining the underlying type:

```
df.style.format({'dates': lambda t: t.strftime('%Y')})
```

This will allow you to keep the type while having a clean visual format

Comment: Noteworthy that the pandas Styler does not work outside of interactive HTML environments like Juypter notebook, and can only be exported to environments which support its formatting like excel, and LaTeX. There is a very similar answer to this one in [How to change the datetime format in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60273382/15497888)