# can't get python to format date correctly

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm reading in a csv file into a new dataframe "df" using

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\projects\tstr_results.csv',index_col=None)
```

The file has a column 'date' that is in a format of `4-Nov-2021`.  df.dtypes shows 'date' to be an object.

I used the following command to the column into a datetime stamp:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%b-%Y')

However, df['date'] shows the date to be `2021-11-04` and as a dtype of datetime64[ns].

Am I missing a parameter to get to the desired format of `04-Nov-2021`?

Comment: You converted your string to a timestamp object. Then you display it. By default its displays it as %Y-%m-%d. You can print it a you wish. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38067805/2681662

Comment: `format` in `to_datetime` is only to `parse` value from `string` to `datetime` - not to format when you display it. You would have to create new column with strings instead of `datetime` and then you can use `strftime` (`string format time`) to create strings with expected `format`. But when you will have strings then you can't make calculations on dates - you can't sort by date, substract date, etc.

Comment: Thank you, MSH and fursa.  The link to the previous posting on this helped.  Unfortunately, since I'm creating a pivot table, I do need the ability act on the date as a date and not string.

I've ended up generating my pivot table and then writing it to a CSV file to read into Excel.  There I can format the date as needed for my report.  I was hoping to do everything in python without using Excel.

Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the right format directly while reading the csv with keyword arguments `parse_dates` and `date_parser`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\projects\tstr_results.csv',index_col=None, parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=lambda d: pd.Timestamp(d).strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))
```

Comment: Thank you, Tranbi, for this.  I modified my pd.read_csv and found it turn 'date' into a datetime64[ns] data type.  But the format didn't take.  It was still 2021-11-04.

I then tried using style.format 
df.style.format({"date": lambda t: t.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")})
on the date as an object and as datetime 64.  Either way, it still turned into year-month-day.

To get my report done, I've exported my results to a csv and used Excel to pretty-up the date to my boss's needs.