# How to change the date format d-m-y to dd-mm-yyyy using pandas

Tags: python

I am trying to change the date format reported in the header. where the date formats reported are as the below
1-2-22 thru 1-8-22,
1-16-22 thru 1-22-22
need to update the date formats to dd-mm-yyyy in the header

Comment: Hope u find your answer in the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_dates = ['2018-10-26 12:00', '2018-10-26 12:00', '2018-10-26 12:00']

dates_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dates, columns=['date'])

dates_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dates_df['date'])


dates_df['date']= dates_df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

print(dates_df)
#          date
# 0  10/26/2018
# 1  10/26/2018
# 2  10/26/2018
```