# how to create a certain pandas data type (date and time with timezone)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utc

I want to use `datetime.datetime.now()` to create the time in the following format to match the output from an API: `2022-02-25T18:05:00+00:00`.

When I use `dtypes` on the API output it says `datetime64[ns, UTC]`. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: No because that doesn't deal with the ```UTC```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), this is as close as you get:

```
>>> df["column"] = df["column"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
>>> df
                     column
0  2022-02-25T20:25:16+0000
```

But you can go all the way operating on the string

```
>>> df["column"] = df["column"].str.slice(stop=-2) + ":" + df["column"].str.slice(start=-2)
>>> df
                      column
0  2022-02-25T20:25:16+00:00
```