# Why is my function parameter for Pandas to_datetime() being ignored?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame with a column containing months and years. Unfortunately, the values are currently string objects not datetime objects; This means that if sorting by this column, the sort goes in numerical rather than chronological order. For example, 01 2020, 01 2021, 01 2022, 02 2020... etc.
I am attempting to convert the column to datetime objects using the pandas.to_datetime() function as documented here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html
This works just fine, but unfortunately changes my format to `yyyy-mm-dd` (making up the day value since there isn't one, and arbitrarily setting it to 01).

I've used the format="" parameter, but it doesn't seem to change anything.
`temp_df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Month'], format="%m %Y")` still results in the same date format, as if my format parameter had been `%Y-%m-%d`.
I've googled this a bunch and come across a number of articles and previous stack overflow posts that tell me how to solve this problem - but their solution is what I'm doing, using to_datetime(df, format). Oh, and this is in a Jupyter notebook if that matters.
Appreciate the help in advance!~

Comment: A bit confused. If you need a datetime, then it must have a day.

Comment: Sure, I know the object must have the day value defined, but am I wrong in thinking you can print it without the day value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60273382 perhaps

Comment: Copy, I'll work with the .style.format() syntax. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Hey, this worked for me, so if you'd like to change to an answer I'm happy to accept it so you get credit