# Convert GPS time to datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe with numerous columns, one of which is the time in GPS time, like such:

| GPS_time |
| --- |
| 1635751985 |
| 1635751985 |
| 1635751986 |
| 1635751987 |
| 1635751987 |
| .......... |

How would I go about converting this to `datetime` or `UTC` within Python?

Comment: what sort of dataframe do you have (such as a Pandas DataFrame)? it will likely provide methods to convert your timestamps to another format

Comment: Sorry, yes it's a Pandas DataFrame. I've been looking for that, but can't seem to find anyting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Pandas `.to_datetime()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to do this conversion!

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": [1635751985, 1635751985, 1635751986]})
>>> df
        dates
0  1635751985
1  1635751985
2  1635751986
>>> pd.to_datetime(df["dates"], unit="s")
0   2021-11-01 07:33:05
1   2021-11-01 07:33:05
2   2021-11-01 07:33:06
Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note that this conversion is from your integer values to *storing* the values as `datetime64[ns]`
Once converted, you can control how they're *displayed* with `.dt.strftime()` (see [How to change the datetime format in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas) )

Comment: Good answer. I did some performance tests (with 100k rows) and this is around 3x faster than manual for-loop.

Comment: Ah, did not realize that would actually work! Goes to show how much there is to learn still with any python package, haha. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This format is called Unix timestamp.

You can convert it to a datetime object like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1635751985)

# use a for-loop to convert multiple items
```

By default, the object will be in your local timezone.

If you want UTC, you can use the [pytz library](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/):

```py
from pytz import timezone

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1635751985, timezone('UTC'))
```

Comment: this will only convert one value at a time, which is very inefficient if they have a large dataframe!

Comment: @ti7 Ah, didn't consider that! Hopefully someone will provide a better answer in that regard. Or I'll update if I should come up with something.