# date in pandas to csv in general format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, datetime

Despite I had value to pandas data frame as string, it is being transformed to date format when I export data frame[image] to CSV file.

I have tried various methods, but the outcome is the same.

Did anyone have a similar problem? If yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: Note that CSV is not a synonym of Excel. This behavior is Excel trying to be helpful (and failing). If you need a string, then *import* the CSV into Excel, specifying that column as text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: Echoing @BigBen above, what is displayed when you open the CSV in notepad?

Comment: in notepad, it is fine(the format of column is not being changed)

Answer (score 3):

I think it has nothing to do with `pandas` or `python` but with the `excel` or `google docs` or any other `spreadsheet software` you are using.

In the case of excel, you can use `=TEXT(date, format)` to convert the `date` into the `text` format.

EDIT: 
You can also specify the `column` as `text` instead of using formula.