# how to change a date format 01oct2012 to 01-10-2012

Tags: python, pandas

I have a weird date format in my data. I currently have 01oct2012 and I would like 01-10-2012. Can someone help me change it! Thank you!

[image: Data]

I tried using the pd.to_datetime, but I dont think I have the right code.

Comment: Have a looking into the `.strptime` method. This will return a `datetime` object based on the user-defined format of the source date string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas Try looking at this , this has been answered previously.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above this question has many answers.  Taking just 1 date as an example:
`ts = pd.to_datetime('01oct2012')` produces the timestamp:
Timestamp('2012-10-01 00:00:00')

To convert to the desired format:

```
ts.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

yields:
'01-10-2012'