# How do I replace "." in my date to "-" in python when working with a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I have the following data frame:

DATE

16.12.2022

15.12.2022

14.12.2022

13.12.2022

12.12.2022

I want to replace the "." in my DATE column with "-"

The current code I was using is as follows:

df2['DATE'] = df2['DATE'].replace('.','-')

But this would provide the following output:

```
0       ----------
1       ----------
2       ----------
3       ----------
4       ----------
```

All of the text in date has been replaced with "-"

Any suggestions as how I can make this work?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas

Comment: do a print(df2.dtypes) and show us the reults

Comment: result['DATE']= pd.to_datetime(result['DATE'], dayfirst=True)