# I have a column date of the form '20041230' . I want to convert this column to the form 2004-12-30

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I Have a column named "Date" which has values of the form '20041230'.
How to convert this to 2004-12-30 in pandas.

I tried applying pd.to_datetime to the column, but I am getting garbage values attached to the date.

Comment: `>>> pd.to_datetime("20041230")` gives
`Timestamp('2004-12-30 00:00:00')` for me. Can you show us your output?

Comment: What type do you want as output? datetime or string? What do you have as input? String or integer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

A safe method to have strings would be:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

For datetime type, use [`normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.normalize()
```