# Converting separate str type columns for date and time into a single datetime type column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My data is in the below format in a pandas dataframe:

```
   date               time
0  Wed Mar 1 2023     7:00p
1  Sun Mar 12 2023    9:00p
```

The dtypes of the above columns are both strings. The 'p' in time stands for PM however all of the times in the dataset are in the PM.

I am trying to convert this into a single column in the datetime format

I first removed the day prefix and changed the month to a number using:
(note data is only from Oct 2022 to April 2023)

```
df.date = df.date.str[4:]

date_replace = {'Oct': '10',
                'Nov': '11',
                'Dec': '12',
                'Jan': '1',
                'Feb': '2',
                'Mar': '3',
                'Apr': '4',
                ' ': '/',
}

df.date = df.date.replace(month_replace, regex=True)
```

This returned the following:

```
   date         time
0  3 1 2023     7:00p
1  3 12 2023    9:00p
```

As you can see the method to replace the white spaces with '/' did not work.

My plan was to then write a function to return the time column into 24 hour time and then concatenate the two columns. I feel like I am doing this in a very inefficient way.

The output I am looking for is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm in datetime format in a single column, e.g.:

```
   date
0  1/3/2023 19:00
1  12/3/2023 21:00
```

Comment: For conversion to datetime, you can specify a [`strftime` format string](https://strftime.org/) however you want - you don't need to jump through hoops to convert it to `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])`

Comment: Try: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')`

Comment: Note that Pandas datetime format is not customizable per se. You can either [convert it to string](/a/38067805/4518341) or [style it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60273382/4518341). Or neither if the exact format doesn't actually matter that much. Pandas uses ISO 8601, which is an international standard.