# Pandas dataframe column datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

Given the following dataframe, how do I change the datetime format from "2023-12-11 00:00:00" to "2023-12-11" for all columns?

When I print the dataframe, colum header are displayed as "2023-12-11" but when I join two dataframes, column headers change to "2023-12-11 00:00:00".

```
>>> positions.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5 entries, EUR_micro to MXP
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------               --------------  -----
 0   2023-12-11 00:00:00  5 non-null      int64
 1   2023-12-12 00:00:00  5 non-null      int64
 2   2023-12-13 00:00:00  5 non-null      int64
 3   2023-12-14 00:00:00  5 non-null      int64
 4   2023-12-15 00:00:00  5 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(5)
memory usage: 240.0+ bytes

>>> print(positions)
             2023-12-11  2023-12-12  2023-12-13  2023-12-14  2023-12-15
EUR_micro            -1          -1          -1          -1          -1
GOLD_micro           -1          -1          -1          -1          -1
SP500_micro           0           1           1           1           1
DAX                   1           1           1           1           1
MXP                   1           1           1           1           1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Comment: No. Can't refer to columns with headers names, as they change every day. Tried to change column format with strftime but got errors, column header is date but data on rows is not.

Comment: please provide an example dataframe to reproduce , It will help you to get the answers fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

I think this is the situation you are talking about.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-03')
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]], columns=cols)
```

df

[image]

df has columns of DatetimeIndex.

but if you make string columns, they got 00:00:00

```
df['col1'] = [4, 8]
```

df

[image]

In fact, they all have 00:00:00, so they are not being generated, but rather showing what was omitted.

**Code**

chk datetime by using `isinstance` and convert '%Y-%m-%d' format

```
from datetime import datetime
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if isinstance(x, datetime)  else x)
```

df

[image]

Comment: It works and is such an elegant one row of magic. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {
    datetime.datetime.strptime('2023-12-11', '%Y-%m-%d'): [-1, -1, 0, 1, 1],
    datetime.datetime.strptime('2023-12-12', '%Y-%m-%d'): [-1, -1, 1, 1, 1],
    
}

index = ['EUR_micro', 'GOLD_micro', 'SP500_micro', 'DAX', 'MXP']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

df.info()
 0   2023-12-11 00:00:00  5 non-null      int64
 1   2023-12-12 00:00:00  5 non-null      int64
```

Convert the column from datetime object to string

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
df.info()
#   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------      --------------  -----
 0   2023-12-11  5 non-null      int64
 1   2023-12-12  5 non-null      int64
```

Comment: This didn't work, I'm assuming because data in rows are strings AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'