# ValueError: time data 'x' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y' (match) when using pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Very simple question but I can't seem to find an answer. The date format in my CSV is in mm/dd/yyyy format specifically 1/16/1962 but i am trying to get it to change to a display of dd/mm/yyyy . But when i try to use pd.to_datetime... specifically

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

it says

```
ValueError: time data '1/16/1962' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y' (match)
```

I tried a number of ways including putting dayfirst = True into the bracket but it seems nothing works

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] and the desired output.

Comment: "*change to a display of dd/mm/yyyy*" - note that if you parse a date represented in a string to a datetime data structure (as `pd.to_datetime` does), you do not have a specific *format* for display. If you want the output to be strings, representing dates, you need to convert datetime to string using `strftime` with an appropriate [directive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) ("format code").

Comment: example of this round-trip: `pd.to_datetime(["1/16/1962"], format="%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`. Note that if your input is a dataframe, you need to use the `dt` accessor; e.g. `pd.to_datetime(column-name-here, format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas

Comment: This question should be re-opened since the linked question and answers do not mention `pd.Index`. A Pandas Index behaves differently from a Pandas Series when it comes to date display. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So many misconceptions here.

1. `pd.to_datetime` doesn't change the format of a string but it converts a string to a [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object. You don't have to feed a format string to this function. Python is smart enough to recognize the format itself. So `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` would be enough.
2. However, if you use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv), you can already parse the dates when reading with `parse_dates=[column_index]`. The square brackets are a list of all column indices with dates, I assume you only have one such column.
3. In Python a date is a first-class object, it doesn't really have a set sequence dd.mm.yyyy, yyyy-mm-dd, mm-dd-yyyy or whatever. Pandas usually displays dates in yyyy-mm-dd format but if it's in an index it uses the format mm/dd/yyyy. [There is no way to change that](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11501).
4. If you really want a specific format and don't need any actual date functionality or sorting, you can convert the index back to a string with `df.index = df.index.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`
5. Python can't guess what separator you want for output. If you want a slash, you have to put a slash, not a hyphen. Like this (for your desired output dd/mm/yyyy): `"%d/%m/%Y"`.

So to print the dataframe with your favourite date format you can do:

```py
import pandas as pd

date_column_index = 0  # Adjust accordingly. 0 would be the first column.
df = pd.read_csv("old.csv", parse_dates=[date_column_index])
df.index = df.index.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print(df)
```

#### Warning for Pandas 1.x.y

While Pandas 1 can correctly guess the particular date format in the OP's CSV, Pandas 1 [badly messes up dates](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/48621) where the day comes before the month. If you're on Pandas 1, you should always pass the expected date format when reading multiple dates. E.g. the OP could use

- `pd.to_datetime(df.index, format="%m/%d/%Y")` or
- `pd.read_csv("old.csv", date_format="%m/%d/%Y")`.

Comment: Yes, but my question is actually how do i read the data as ddmmyyyy in pandas? Not n CSV....thanks

Comment: @oldradishsoip can you please edit your question to clarify what you want? The question says your data is in mm/dd/yyyy format, now it's suddenly ddmmyyyy?

Comment: @oldradishsoip I've answered how to convert a string to a date directly in Pandas: either pass the correct format string to `pd.to_datetime` or leave it out completely.

Comment: Hi hi thanks for the info but that's not what im looking for...i know that my csv dates are in mm/dd/yy format, and you have explained that i can pass the argument to read it etc but I am essentially trying to do is to change it to dd/mm/yyyy format. Not in CSV, but in python itself. How do i do that in a simple manner?

Comment: basically I want the dates to come out as dd/mm/yyyy in my dataframe after reading the CSV

Comment: Do you want to convert them to string or just display them in a different way? Please edit your question to clarify what you want.

Comment: done...changed the question to display

Comment: Have you tried step 1 in my list?

Comment: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) only converts it to the current formet of mm/dd/yy but i want it to be dislayed as dd/mm/yy.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Perhaps the display depends on your locale settings? It's usually yyyy-mm-dd. What version of Pandas are you using (`pd.__version__`)? What locale are you on? `import locale; locale.getlocale()`

Comment: Nevermind. I could reproduce. Date display is such a mess in Pandas. Anyhow, steps 1 & 4 should work for you.